# php mysql wrong value from timestamp column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table that holds property for sale data, I record when then property is first listed in the column 'Added' and when the property details are updated I record the date and time in the 'Updated' Column.

This all works fine but when I run a query with php and return the row the value of the 'Updated' column is being returned as the current time.

Here is my table structure :

[image]

My query I use is this

```
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = 5030238");

while ($p = $query->fetch()) {
    $added = $p['Added'];
    $updated = $p['Updated'];
}
```

Expected output would be the variables to equal this:

```
$added = '2018-05-10 19:23:51'
$updated = '2018-05-11 09:55:11'
```

But the `$updated` is giving me the current time and date instead!

Does any one know what is wrong here?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual Data Type for that column?

Comment: HI twisty its  a timestamp

Comment: Strange. Can you add something that might perform `var_export($p)` someplace?